# Functions and parameters in python 2.7.3

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, parameter-passing, computer-science

In my Computer Science class, I am just starting to learn about Functions and parameters in python.  Right now my instructor is making us learn parameter passing.  Instead of typing a huge summarization of my program I just retyped the assignment guide down below.

**Description:** In this program the user will have to option of entering a charge, entering a payment or displaying the balance on their credit card.  Allow the user to indicate their choice by entering a code at the keyboard.

Use the following function names:

- enterValue     the user enters a value
- addCharge       the value passed to the function is added to the balance
- addPayment      the value passed to the function is subtracted from the balance
- showBalance     the current balance on the credit card is displayed

Have the user enter the following codes for the appropriate actions:

- "C" for entering charges
- "P" for entering payments
- "B" for showing the balance
- Allow the entry of transactions until "Z" is entered

## Program

```
balance = 0
def enterValue ():
    enter = input ("Enter a value.")
    return enter

def addCharge (enter,balance):
    balance = balance + enter
    return balance

def addPayment (enter,balance):
    balance = balance - enter
    return balance
def showBalance ():
    print "Your balance is... ", balance


transaction = raw_input ("Enter C for charges, P for payments, and B to show your balance. ") 
enterValue ()
while transaction != "Z":


    if transaction == "C":
        balance = addCharge(enter,balance)
        showBalance()        
    elif transaction == "P": 
        balance = addPayment (enter,balance)
        showBalance()
    elif transaction =="B":
        balance = enterValue()
        showBalance()
    transaction = raw_input ("Enter C for charges, P for payments, and B to show your balance. ")
```

## Output

```
Enter C for charges, P for payments, and B to show your balance. P

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chrisblive/Downloads/Charge_Braverman-2.py", line 26, in <module>
    balance = addPayment (enter,balance)
NameError: name 'enter' is not defined
```

(My problem is that my value inside of `enterValue()` is not being defined.)

Comment: Your problem is that `enter` is not defined *outside* the function.  When you do `addPayment(enter, balance)`, what are you expecting `enter` to be?

Comment: enter is not define before you call it in addCharge.

Comment: also there is no need for you to pass enter to enterValue since you are overriding it.

Comment: @BrenBarn in addPayment and addCharge I am expecting enter to be the value the user types in at the beginning of the program.  Does that help?

Comment: But they don't type it in, because you never call the enterValue function.

Comment: Oh... so many things. probably the easiest thing is to call `enter = enterValue()` at the beginning of the program. Or just say `enter = input ("Enter a value.")` but not inside a function

Comment: Also I fail to see how this could be described as "computer science". This is introductory programming, which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: That's what my computer science curriculum was like.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Im in highschool. But next year they are changing the course name to introduction to programming.

Comment: Also balance will showBalance() will technically work here, but its good practice to pass your variable to the function, unless you specifically define `global balance`

Comment: @Hoopdady If I didn't have to put enter in a function I would be done with this program already, but my teacher is making us.

Comment: Ha. I'm not sure what your teacher's trying to accomplish here. He either wants you to set a global variable of `enter` or say `enter = enterValue()`. My guess is the latter. And if you do it that way. The function `enterValue()` can just be one line `return raw_input('Enter a value.')`.

Comment: @Hoopdady sorry I'm a noob. Thanks though.  Your comment made me remember that I forgot say enter = enterValue()

Comment: Haha. Its ok. We've all been there. I'm so glad to here they're teaching python in high school. They only taught it as an elective in college, and made us learn c++... so lame.

Comment: @Hoopdady The next course I could take is Advanced programming, and that's where I could learn C++ and Java.  I don't think I'm going to take it though.  I'm not a great programmer (My teacher doesn't seem to get that).  I'm just good at problem solving and finishing my work.

Comment: Return value of call `enterValue ()` is unused.

Answer (score -1):

The main charge of the exercise is to understand passing parameters to functions.
So just pass all needed variables in the functions to it!
Approximately you can say that all functions have their own namespaces an if you want to use a value of another level in it, you have to pass it as a parameter and return it if you want to reuse it in a lower level.

For example:

```
###   Level "enterValue"   ###
def enterValue():
    return float(raw_input("Enter a value: "))
### End Level "enterValue" ###

###   Level "addCharge"   ###
def addCharge(enter, balance):
    balance = balance + enter
    return balance
### End Level "addCharge" ###

###   Level "showBalance"   ###
def showBalance(balance):
    print "Your balance is %f" % balance
### End Level "showBalance" ###

### Level "Mainlevel" ###
# This is where your program starts.
transaction = None
balance = 0.0
while transaction != "Z":
    transaction = raw_input("Enter C for charges, P for payments, and B to show your balance.\nEnter Z to exit: ").upper()

    if transaction == "C":
        enter = enterValue()
        balance = addCharge(enter, balance)
        showBalance(balance)
    elif transaction == "P":
        balance = addPayment(enter, balance)
        showBalance(balance)
    elif transaction == "B":
        showBalance(balance)
### End Level "Mainlevel" ###
```